# Time left calculation not working PHP

Tags: php

I am doing a website where I needed to calculate the time left somewhere.both time(), and $endTime work properly individually but this calculation doesn't seem to work
(it always shows 02:00:00):

```
$timeLeft = date('H:i:s',max(($endTime - time()) , 0));
```

Where is the problem?

edit:
$endTime = 1296727200

Comment: What is the value for `$endTime`?

Comment: Needs basic debugging. What does `$endTime` contain? If the result is a negative value, you will always get `0` which translates to January 1970, 02:00:00 in your time zone. Also this will break with countdown values > 24 hours

Comment: that's a date in the past so the result will always be negative... Can you use PHP 5.3? The `DateInterval` class is great for stuff like this (http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

found the answer thanks to the comments,
the problem is that the $endTime was already smaller then time(), and then date(0)= January 1970, 02:00:00 in my timezone so it will be 02:00:00

Comment: As mentionned by Pekka, this breaks for durations of more than one day.

Answer (score 2):

The function `date` expects an *timestamp* (a number of seconds since 1970/1/1) as argument while `$endTime - time()` is a *duration*. You can compute the number of minutes and hours that duration represents as:

```
$seconds = $endTime - time();
$minutes = $seconds / 60;
$seconds = $seconds - $minutes * 60;
$hours = $minutes / 60;
$minutes = $minutes - $hours * 60;
$timeLeft = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
```

Of course `$endTime` should not be in the past…